# Can't call EJB 3 security methods without @PermitAll

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb

I have an EJB 3.0 Sesion Bean including a "Hello World" Remote Interface and a "HelloWorldBean" SessionBean. Now I tried to add some security to them. This is my SessionBean:

```
@Stateful
@SecurityDomain("other")
@DeclareRoles("ejb")
@PermitAll
public class HelloWorldBean implements HelloWorld {
@Resource
private SessionContext context;

/**
 * Default constructor.
 */
public HelloWorldBean() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


@Override
@PermitAll
public String sayHello() throws Exception {
    String s = this.toString();
    s = s + " Security: "+context.isCallerInRole("ejb") + " "+context.getCallerPrincipal().getName();
    return s;
}
}
```

I used `@PermitAll` to test the application in general and it works. If I leave the upper annotation I get an exception that tells me that I'm not allowed to call the method     `sayHello()`. The method `getCallerPrincipal().getName()` always returns "anonymous". The following class is my standalone client.

```
public class EjbAccess3_1_v2 {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String providerUrl = "remote://localhost:4447";
        final String appName = "NewApplication";
        final String moduleName = "EJB3.1";
        final String distinctName = "";
        final String beanName = "HelloWorldBean";
        final String viewClassName = HelloWorld.class.getName();
        final String ejbPath= appName + "/" + moduleName +  "/" + beanName + "!" + viewClassName;        

        Properties environment = new Properties();
        environment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
        environment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, providerUrl);
        environment.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
        environment.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
        environment.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "ejb");
        environment.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");
        InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext(environment); 
        HelloWorld remote = (HelloWorld) initialContext.lookup(ejbPath);

        System.out.println("EJB V3.1 v2");
        System.out.println(remote.sayHello());

    }
}
```

I'm using JBoss 6 as the application server and created an application user "ejb". The client is working as long as I don't use any security or use the `@PermitAll` at the SessionBean class and the method, which I want to call. I hope somebody can help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have a user called "ejb" and a role called "ejb". If the user and the role are not yet mapped to each other then you need to [map them 1st somehow](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.2/html/Security_Guide/Configure_User_Role_Assignment_using_jboss-cli.sh.html).

If already mapped then you need to use the annotation

```
@RolesAllowed({"ejb"})
```

on class or methods like [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ejb/ejb_security.htm).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to create a role "ejb" but that didn't work, so I mapped the user "ejb" to the role "administrator", after that I tried to declare the security as shown in your second link, but it does not work. I tried DeclareRoles and RolesAllowed both with "ejb" and "administrator". The result is the same, I am not allowed to call the method. I also added the configuration file (from your second link) to my META-INF folder as jboss.xml, but nothing changes

Comment: I tested some more cases now and I got at least a small success. Right now the getName() Method of the Principal returns "ejb" instead of anonymous, but still I'm not allowed to call the method.